# How to exclude weekends in date object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I'm facing issue with excluding weekend dates in JavaScript.For my business requirement I want to exclude 3 days from date object Friday, Saturday and Sunday in every week.What I need here is the values of Friday should display as Monday, Saturday as Tuesday and Sunday as Wednesday. I'm able to do this.

The issue that I'm facing here is when we run the above example the a[0] value should be 21-SEP-2017 but I'm getting 20-SEP-2017 and remaining array values should not change. So please do help me out in resolving this issue

```
var a = ["21-SEP-2017", "22-SEP-2017", "23-SEP-2017", "24-SEP-2017", "25-SEP-2017"];
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  var startDate = a[i];
  startDate = new Date(startDate.replace(/-/g, "/"));

  var endDate = "",
      noOfDaysToAdd = 1;
  var count = 0;
  endDate = new Date(startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate()));

  if (startDate.getDay() != 0 && startDate.getDay() != 5 && startDate.getDay() != 6) {
    endDate = new Date(startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + i - 1));
  } else {
    startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 3)
    endDate = new Date(startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate()));
  }
  console.log(endDate); //You can format this date as per your requirement
}
```

Comment: Cool. What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Are you familiar with libraries like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)?

Comment: This is my array var a = ["21-SEP-2017","22-SEP-2017","23-SEP-2017","24-SEP-2017","25-SEP-2017"] I want output dates as  21-SEP-2017,25-SEP-2017,26-SEP-2017,27-SEP-2017,28-SEP-2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems not finished: the variables `noOfDaysToAdd` and `count` are never used, and if they were, they would be reset in every iteration of the loop, which cannot be the purpose.

That your output shows 20 September is because you did not output a stringified version of the date, but the date object itself, and then `console.log` will display the date as a UTC date (notice the time part matches the timezone difference). Instead use `.toString()` or another way to turn the date to a localised string.

Here is how you could do it:

```js
function toDate(s) {
    return new Date(s.replace(/-/g, '/'));
}

function toStr(dt) {
    var months = ["JAN","FEB","MAR","APR","MAY","JUN",
                  "JUL","AUG","SEP","OCT","NOV","DEC"];
    return [('0'+dt.getDate()).substr(-2), months[dt.getMonth()], dt.getFullYear()]
           .join('-');
}

var a = ["21-SEP-2017", "22-SEP-2017", "23-SEP-2017", "24-SEP-2017", "25-SEP-2017"],
    add = 0;
var result = a.map(toDate).map(dt => {
    dt.setDate(dt.getDate()+add);
    var move = [0, 6, 5].indexOf(dt.getDay()) + 1;
    if (move) {
        add += move;
        dt.setDate(dt.getDate()+move);
    }
    return dt;
}).map(toStr);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: if I add one more date to my input
["21-SEP-2017", "22-SEP-2017", "23-SEP-2017", "24-SEP-2017", "25-SEP-2017","26-SEP-2017"]
this is the output I'm getting
["21-SEP-2017", "25-SEP-2017", "26-SEP-2017", "27-SEP-2017", "28-SEP-2017", "02-OCT-2017"]
The issue that we need to resolve is no dates to be on same date and all dates to be in sequence and we need to exclude weekends.

Comment: I don't understand: you want 29-SEP-2017 to be in the output, but you also want to *"...exclude 3 days from date object Friday, Saturday and Sunday in every week"*. But 29-SEP-2017 is a Friday. Do you see the contradiction? The first day that would be acceptable is the next Monday, i.e. 02-OCT-2017...